# Why is this fallback font not loading in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, context

I used the following code to set the fallback font. My intention is that, whenever the Chinese text appears, it will switch to SourceHanSerifTC-Heavy.otf, otherwise it will use Garamond. however, it isn't switching fonts at all.

```
\definefontfallback[garamond-fallback][file:~/.fonts/4/SourceHanSerifTC-Heavy.otf][force=yes]

\starttypescript[serif]                         [garamond]
    \definefontsynonym[Serif]                   [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf][fallbacks=garamond-fallback]
    \definefontsynonym[SerifBold]               [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-AllSC.otf][fallbacks=garamond-fallback]
    \definefontsynonym[SerifItalic]             [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-Italic.otf][fallbacks=garamond-fallback]
    \definefontsynonym[SerifBoldItalic]         [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-AllSC.otf][fallbacks=garamond-fallback]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript[sans]                          [garamond]
    \definefontsynonym[Sans]                    [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf][fallbacks=garamond-fallback]
    \definefontsynonym[SansBold]                [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-AllSC.otf][fallbacks=garamond-fallback]
    \definefontsynonym[SansItalic]              [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-Italic.otf][fallbacks=garamond-fallback]
    \definefontsynonym[SansBoldItalic]          [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-AllSC.otf][fallbacks=garamond-fallback]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript[garamond]
    \definetypeface[garamond]                   [rm][serif][garamond][default]
    \definetypeface[garamond]                   [ss][sans][garamond][default]
    \definetypeface[garamond]                   [mm][math][modern][default]
\stoptypescript


\setupbodyfont[garamond, 12pt]

\starttext

    This should be in garamond, except the Chinese writing.
    猫
\stoptext
```

Why is this not successfully displaying the Chinese text? I tried testing with a variety of other fonts, but still no success.

Comment: Use `\definefallbackfamily` and try specifying a Unicode range (see [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Unicode_blocks_in_ConTeXt), e.g. `range={...},force=yes`

Comment: Well, a wild guess. I haven't tried it here, but since it works for `\definefontfamily`, perhaps it works for typescripts too.